# MySql combine two columns into single new column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following structure with a MySQL table.

```
+----------------+----------------+
|    data 1      |      data2     |
+----------------+----------------+
|     1          |     2          |
+----------------+----------------+
```

And i want to combine above 2 columns into one column like this:

```
+---------------------+
|      data           |
+---------------------+
|          1          |
+---------------------+
|          2          |
+---------------------+
```

Any Way Thanks - for your help  :)

Answer (score 1):

Use UNION - if you want have the merged column to have distinct value else use UNION All

```
SELECT data1 AS data FROM yourTable
UNION
SELECT data2 AS data FROM yourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `UNION`:

```
SELECT data1 AS data FROM yourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT data2 AS data FROM yourTable
```